# error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406) while calling the api

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

I am getting below error, when i execute the api with this url. I searched this got few answers as well but in all those questions they have used explicitly headers which i have not given.

http://localhost:8290/dataengine/api/program/ff808081657a701801660aa6c6160001/customer/username/muddassir91@gmail.c

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Thu Apr 25 16:29:23 IST 2019
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
>   Could not find acceptable representation

But when I execute the api with these values it works fine.
http://localhost:8290/dataengine/api/program/ff808081657a701801660aa6c6160001/customer/username/muddassir91@gmail.co
OR
http://localhost:8290/dataengine/api/program/ff808081657a701801660aa6c6160001/customer/username/muddassir91@gmail.com

This is my api

```
@CrossOrigin
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/program/{programId}/customer/username/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ApiResponse<Customer> getCustomerByUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username, @PathVariable("programId") String programId) {

    return new ApiResponse<Customer>(APIResponseKey.ALL_GOOD, customerService.getCustomerByUserName(username, programId), null);
}
```

POM.XML

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
```